# How to log Keycode and unicode on Keyevent

Tags: android, special-characters, android-softkeyboard, keyevent, keycode

I want to know the keycode for some chars like Divide symbol in mobile, Euro etc..

Updating the question I am able to print all key events using below method. But nothing happens when I type few chars from soft keyboard as shown in the image.[image: Keys Underlined are not working]

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent KEvent) {
    int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();
    if (keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int keycode = KEvent.getKeyCode();
        int keyunicode = KEvent.getUnicodeChar(KEvent.getMetaState());
        char character = (char) keyunicode;
        Log.d(TAG, "DEBUG MESSAGE KEY=" + character + " KEYCODE=" + keycode);
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(KEvent);
}
```

Comment: KEYCODE_YEN = 216;  even though I am passing keycode 216  to webview nothing is displayed in the webview

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent